# HikariCP as JNDI Datasource in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, hikaricp

I have trying to test HikariCP as jndi datasource, but i cannot find the way to add it as jndi datasource in weblogic.

If it's possible can you provide the configuration or if not can you add this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

I saw this article a bit ago on the subject: 
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.)

It describes several issues about JNDI connections to weblogic with hicaricp.  One of the major issues is Connection Pooling which is static.

Examples are all over in the Article in GITHUB, but one of the main examples I re-pasted below from there:

**HikariCP includes a JNDI DataSource factory that can be used with Tomcat or other containers.**

Example (Tomcat) configurations:

Driver-based:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/OracleHikari" auth="Container"
      factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      minimumIdle="5" 
      maximumPoolSize="10"
      connectionTimeout="300000"
      jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@orcl_server:1521:orcl"
      dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true" 
      dataSource.user="user"
      dataSource.password="pwd" />
```

DataSource-based:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/OracleHikari" auth="Container"
      factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      minimumIdle="5" 
      maximumPoolSize="10"
      connectionTimeout="300000"
      dataSourceClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
      dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true" 
      dataSource.user="user"
      dataSource.password="pwd"
      dataSource.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@orcl_server:1521:orcl"/>
```

A MariaDB example:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDs" auth="Container"
        factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        minimumIdle="5" 
        maximumPoolSize="10"
        connectionTimeout="300000"
        dataSourceClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource"
        dataSource.serverName="localhost"
        dataSource.port="3306"
        dataSource.databaseName="myDatabase"
        dataSource.user="username"
        dataSource.password="password"
        />
</Context>
```

Hope this works for you.
If not, please provide more info.
Thanks.